# What do differently coloured slimes drop?

Tags: stardew-valley

By breeding different slimes together, the child will have a mix of the parents' colour, with a small chance of natural variation. If the colour is different enough, the slime may gain its own unique drops, for example a yellow slime can drop gold ore.

Is there a full list of distinct colours with different drops? What are all of the known ones?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These are the kinds of slimes that are not normally found in the wild:

- Orange Slime, which drops copper ore
- White Slime, which drops iron ore
- Yellow Slime, which drops gold ore
- Grey Slime, which drops stone
- Black Slime, which drops coal and has a chance to drop bixite and neptunite

It is possible to breed slimes of any colour and shade, but only those 5 colours will provide unique drops. Everything else will fall under green, blue, red, or purple.